# Cloning the json response from the server into another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hell guys,

I am getting a json response from the PHP script like this:

```js
function getAuctionItems()
{  
        var copiedObject = {};
        var jqxhr = $.post( "php/server.php", {command:'auctions'},function() {})
          .done(function(data) {
                
                if(data){
                    copiedObject =data;
                }
                else{
                }
           });

          return copiedObject;
}
```

As you can see the data contains the json results (data is all fine) but when i want to return the results it returns empty object.... how do i return the data from this ajax request so that the other function will use it? Obviously I cannot simply clone copiedObject =data;

Comment: The `post` function is **async** this means you can't have your `return` statement outside your success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post call is asynchronous, so you have to use the value from the done function.  Generally, you would do something like:

```
function getAuctionItems()
{  
        var copiedObject = {};
        var jqxhr = $.post( "php/server.php", {command:'auctions'},function() {})
          .done(function(data) {

                if(data){
                    dosomethingWithData(data);
                }
                else{
                }
           });
}

function dosomethingWithData(data) {
  doSomethingwithThedata.......
}
```

Because JavaScript isn't waiting around for an expensive process like a post, it has moved on, and is waiting for the done event to actually parse the data.

Comment: Thank you ! This approach is similar too Drew and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example how to do it-

```
$.ajax
    (
        {
            url:"ajax_state_load/"+$('#country_data').val(),success:function(result)
            {
                $("#car_model").html(result);
                $('#region_data')
                    .empty()
                    .append(result);
                ;
            }
            ,error:function()
            { 
                console.error('Region Load Failed.');
            }
        }
    );
```

And everything should be inside

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

If you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "copiedObject" is returned before the post request is completed.

You might need something like...

```
if(data)
{
  myOtherFunction(data);
}
```

Where "myOtherFunction" is a function you create to handle the returned data.
Drew

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of handling this is by passing a callback to your function:

```
function getAuctionItems(callback)
{  
    $.post( "php/server.php", {command:'auctions'},function() {})
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Then, call like this:

```
getAuctionItems(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this approach works too !

Comment: @KushtrimAbdiu this approach has the advantage that the callback function name is not static within the code, as it's being passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are async in nature. Javascript won't wait for the response before returning copiedObject.

Using callback is working fine, but a more elegant way is using Deferred and Promise. It has more flexibility and decouple your ajax calls to your business logic.

To convert your code into Deferred/Promise way.

```
function getAuctionItems()
{         
    return $.post( "php/server.php", {command:'auctions'});
}
```

Then in other method, call like this:

```
getAuctionItems().done(function(data){
     //your logic to process data
});
```

Moreover, if you want to cache your data locally and make the data-fetching logic completely decoupled from your data-processing logic.

```
var dataCached = null;

function fetchData(user){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    if(dataCached != null){
        dfd.resolve(dataCached);
    }else{
         $.post("three.htm", {
              user: user
          },function(data){
               dataCached = data;
              dfd.resolve(data);
         }); 
    } 

    return dfd.promise();
}

$.when(fetchData("Jack")).then(function(data){
   //play with the data
});
```